# Install different versions of python 2

Tags: python, virtualenv

My system is ubuntu 18.04.
I have a pre-installed version 3 and 2 of python.

```
which python3
/usr/bin/python3
python3 -V
Python 3.6.9

which python
/usr/bin/python
python -V
Python 2.7.17
```

I need to create several virtual environments, one for python 2.7.15 and another for 2.6. how can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv)

Comment: You need to install first the version of python you want to use and THEN set up a virtualenv based on that version

Comment: @Marco that's the question, how do I do it?

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads/ hre you find all python versions; you have to download the one you want then untar / unzip it and open README to see how to install. Once is installed you follow answer 2

Comment: how to install python I know, I don't understand how to install 2.7 and 2.6 together for example

Comment: Install Python 2.6; then you have access to the `python2.6` and `python2.7` commands to differentiate between them. Just make sure you don't install 2.6 in a default location, since that may likely mess up your system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways of creating virtual python environments. Three popular ones are

- virtualenv
- pipenv
- conda

I personally like conda a lot.

### virtualenv

Assuming you have `pip` installed, you get virtualenv with

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Once installed, you can change into a directory of your choice and create a virtual environment like this

```
virtualenv myenvironmentname
```

If you want to use a different python version in your virtual environment, you can specify this with the `--python` flag.

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.6 myenvironmentname
```

However, please note that this requires you to have the python version you specify installed in advance, virtualenv will not take care of that for you (have a look at [Use different Python version with virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv/39713544#39713544) for more details). So you'll need local installations of the versions you desire.

You then can activate the environment with

```
myenvironmentname/bin/activate
```

and go ahead to use pip to install packages, etc. Have a look at

```
pip freeze --help
```

to find out on how to make your environment reusable.

### pipenv

`pipenv` combines pip and virtualenv.

You can install it using

```
pip install --user pipenv
```

Pipenv takes care of dependencies on a project basis

```
cd myprojectfolder
pipenv install
```

This will create a `Pipfile` which will track dependencies and a virtualenv (see https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/ for more details).

To create an environment using a specific version, you can do

```
pipenv install --python '/usr/bin/python2.6'
```

or

```
pipenv install --python 2.6
```

Cmp. [Set python version when creating virtualenv using pipenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50161551/set-python-version-when-creating-virtualenv-using-pipenv). If you also have `pyenv` installed, the second form will prompt `pipenv` to attempt to install non-existing versions, afaik.

### conda

Anaconda Python is a python distribution (with a focus on data science) that comes with its own package and virtual environment manager named conda. Anaconda Python is not available in the official package repository of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS but needs to be installed in another way (the official documentation can be found here: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/).

To create an environment with conda, do

```
conda create --name myenvironmentname python=2.7.15
```

In contrast to `virtualenv`, the environments are by default not created in the present working directory, but installed into the `envs` directory in your conda directory. `conda` will also take care to install the proper python version, that is at least as long as it is part of the default channel (see below).

You can then activate said environment with

```
conda activate myenvironmentname
```

As I wrote above, the python version you specify needs to be available from the configured conda channels. python2.6 however, was removed from the default channel. To remedy this, you can add the free channel back to your default list (see https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/free-channel.html for more details):

```
conda config --set restore_free_channel true
```

After that you can

```
conda create --name myotherenvironmentname python=2.6
```

And switch between the environments as you like

```
conda activate myotherenvironmentname
```

Answer (score -1):

For python3 `python -m venv <your_virtual_enviroment_path>` for python2 `virtualenv <your_virutal_enviroment_path>`

The to activate `source <your_virtual_environment_path>/bin/activate`. And to deactivate `deactivate`. Finally to check what is activated `echo $VIRTUAL_ENV`

I strongly recommend for one virtual environment for each project.

Comment: But I cant have python 2.7.15. I can only specify the path to the installed version of python 2.7.17 but that's not what I need.

Comment: you can use the `-p` option, http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/virtualenv.1.html