# Cannot install pipenv python version

Tags: python, pipenv

I am trying to run the command

```
pipenv install python==3.7.9
```

and getting the error below. When I run

```
which python
```

it shows "/Users/Micky/opt/anaconda3/bin/python" and the version is 3.7.9.

Can anyone tell me how?

```
Micky-MBP:sportanalitica Micky$ pipenv install python==3.7.9
Installing python==3.7.9...
Error:  An error occurred while installing python==3.7.9!
Error text: 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python==3.7.9
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python==3.7.9

✘ Installation Failed
```

Comment: Hi it shows the same Python 3.7.9 and which python3 points to /Users/Micky/opt/anaconda3/bin/python

Comment: not helpful - trying to use 3.7.9 version which i have on my mac

Answer (score 1):

**Pipenv is not used to install Python versions**. You install Python separately and then use Pipenv to create and manage virtual environments, using `pipenv install <package>` to install Python packages.

I think what you are trying to do is to create a virtual environment that uses your Python 3.7.9 version. To do that the correct way of specifying the Python version is to pass it as a `--python=</path/to/python>` option. For example, for [`pipenv shell`](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/cli/#pipenv-shell):

```
~$ pipenv shell --help
Usage: pipenv shell [OPTIONS] [SHELL_ARGS]...

  Spawns a shell within the virtualenv.

Options:
  ...
  --python TEXT       Specify which version of Python virtualenv should use.
```

The same option is available to `pipenv install`. So if you have "*python3 points to /Users/Micky/opt/anaconda3/bin/python*":

```
~$ pipenv shell --python=/Users/Micky/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Note that you have to pass the `--python` option *only when creating the virtual environment*. Once it's created, it will "remember" it in the Pipfile to use that version.

```
temp$ pipenv shell --python=/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/python3
...
✔ Successfully created virtual environment! 
...
Creating a Pipfile for this project...
Launching subshell in virtual environment...
...

(temp) temp$ python -V
Python 3.7.9
```

Once your virtual environment, you use `pipenv install <package>` to install Python packages (not Python itself):

```
(temp) temp$ pipenv install somepackage
(temp) temp$ pipenv install somepackage==1.0.0
```

I recommend reading the [Basic Usage of Pipenv docs](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#basic-usage-of-pipenv).

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, I understand that you wish to use a specific version of Python in your Pipenv. It looks like the way you are passing the parameters is wrong. The parameters you are passing is more for packages and not the version of Python.

- To learn more on how to specify the Python version, please refer
  [here](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basics.html#specifying-versions-of-python). `$ pipenv install --python 3.7.9`
- To specify the full path to your Python binary, you may
  refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55363179/6893561). `$ pipenv install --python /Users/Micky/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`
- Lastly, there is a trick you can use, which is to just `pipenv install`. Then once you have a Pipfile, modify the Python version. Then use `pipenv --rm` to remove the install. Next `pipenv install` for the second time and it should take the version specified in the Pipfile which you modified earlier.