# How to use a different Python version for a pipenv project?

Tags: python, pip, path

I am starting a python project that needs Python 3.6 and on my computer I have only installed Python 3.9(which is added to PATH).

When I am installing Python 3.6, should I add it to PATH because Python 3.9 is already added to PATH? If yes, what can I do to specify what Python version I want to use?

When installing a package, how can I specify that I want to use Python 3.6 to install this package?

How can I change my command prompt to use Python 3.6 instead of Python 3.9?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set python version when creating virtualenv using pipenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50161551/set-python-version-when-creating-virtualenv-using-pipenv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When builiding the enviroment using pipenv you can specify the version you want to use for example: pipenv --python 3.6

on some cases a direct path to the python is needed but an appriprate message will show in that case.